# Avaya CMS script

Tags: avaya

First: what the programing langauge avaya cms written in ?

Second: I save cms script that take extention (.ACS), I want to understand this script to start develop it . So please check below script and this script export data from real time and I want to export it every 1 second but when I execute this code it takes about 20 sec that because in every time execute code it starts to connect to server and get report. So how can I keep connecting to server and get data every 1 sec automatic without execute script every time?

code :

```vb
Public Sub Main()

'## cvs_cmd_begin
'## ID = 2001
'## Description = "Report: Real-Time: Designer: Split/Skill Report (All Queues Reports): Export Data"
'## Parameters.Add "Report: Real-Time: Designer: Split/Skill Report (All Queues Reports): Export Data","_Desc"
'## Parameters.Add "Reports","_Catalog"
'## Parameters.Add "2","_Action"
'## Parameters.Add "1","_Quit"
'## Parameters.Add "Real-Time\Designer\Split/Skill Report (All Queues Reports)","_Report"
'## Parameters.Add "1","_ACD"
'## Parameters.Add "-120","_Top"
'## Parameters.Add "525","_Left"
'## Parameters.Add "19440","_Width"
'## Parameters.Add "11760","_Height"
'## Parameters.Add "default","_TimeZone"
'## Parameters.Add "The report Real-Time\Designer\Split/Skill Report (All Queues Reports) was not found on ACD 1.","_ReportNotFound"
'## Parameters.Add "*","_BeginProperties"
'## Parameters.Add "3035;3099;3031;3033;3059;3089;3090","Splits/Skills"
'## Parameters.Add "3035;3099;3031;3033;3059;3089;3090","Split/Skill"
'## Parameters.Add "3035;3099;3031;3033;3059;3089;3090","Split/Skill(Agent)"
'## Parameters.Add "*","_EndProperties"
'## Parameters.Add "*","_BeginViews"
'## Parameters.Add "*","_EndViews"
'## Parameters.Add "D:\xampp\htdocs\cms\real_time.txt","_Output"
'## Parameters.Add "59","_FldSep"
'## Parameters.Add "0","_TextDelim"
'## Parameters.Add "True","_NullToZero"
'## Parameters.Add "True","_Labels"
'## Parameters.Add "True","_DurSecs"

   On Error Resume Next

   cvsSrv.Reports.ACD = 1
   Set Info = cvsSrv.Reports.Reports("Real-Time\Designer\Split/Skill Report (All Queues Reports)")

   If Info Is Nothing Then
      If cvsSrv.Interactive Then
          MsgBox "The report Real-Time\Designer\Split/Skill Report (All Queues Reports) was not found on ACD 1.", vbCritical Or vbOKOnly, "Avaya CMS Supervisor"
      Else
          Set Log = CreateObject("ACSERR.cvsLog") 
          Log.AutoLogWrite "The report Real-Time\Designer\Split/Skill Report (All Queues Reports) was not found on ACD 1."
          Set Log = Nothing
      End If
   Else

       b = cvsSrv.Reports.CreateReport(Info,Rep)
       If b Then
    
          Rep.Window.Top = -120
          Rep.Window.Left = 525
          Rep.Window.Width = 19440
          Rep.Window.Height = 11760        
    
          Rep.TimeZone = "default"
    
          Rep.SetProperty "Splits/Skills","3035;3099;3031;3033;3059;3089;3090"
    
          Rep.SetProperty "Split/Skill","3035;3099;3031;3033;3059;3089;3090"
    
          Rep.SetProperty "Split/Skill(Agent)","3035;3099;3031;3033;3059;3089;3090"
    
          b = Rep.ExportData("D:\xampp\htdocs\cms\real_time.txt", 59, 0, True, True, True)

          Rep.Quit

              If Not cvsSrv.Interactive Then cvsSrv.ActiveTasks.Remove Rep.TaskID
          Set Rep = Nothing
       End If

   End If
   Set Info = Nothing
'## cvs_cmd_end

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Avaya scripts are written in VBScript. If you are familiar with VBA in Office, the code is very similar. They are, unfortunately, slow and kind of crappy. Using an Avaya script to connect to the server every 1 second is just not feasible. You could, maybe, use a Do...Loop but my experience with writing custom VBS for CMS scripts says that even a slight error will result in 100% CPU usage while your non working code runs forever until you manually crash it.

One thing I can say is that every line starting with ‘## is more-or-less documentation about what the script is doing. The ‘ symbol in vbscript is for comments. The actual code is in the below section.

Avaya does have database connectors, which will probably be better for your needs. They’re a lot faster and generally play much nicer with the software. I’d say that’s a more fruitful line of inquiry for polling the DB than macguyvering a script.